# How to convert a Firefox Addon into phpBB Extension?

Tags: php

Hello to all supporting members,

I have a Firefox Addon, and I want to make it an extension for our phpBB boards. So I need to know the steps to convert an addon into extensions.
This Addon is found at here: 
https://github.com/mohancloudworld/Parivartan
As I have seen that any Extension may need these arguments:

```
* @param \phpbb\request\request => $request
* @param \phpbb\template\template => $template
* @param \phpbb\user => $user
* @param \phpbb\auth\auth => $auth
* @param \phpbb\db\driver\driver => $db
* @param \phpbb\config\config => $config
```

On the basis of files presents in this folder, how much files may need to create yet. The files present in this folder is named as:

1. Misc /Parivartan-icon.svg => Icon Image
2. Src/.jpmignore
3. Src/package.json
4. Src/data/myTables.js
5. Src/data/myTables.json
6. Src/lib/main.js
7. Src/lib/myModule.js

Please give me the way through which it is possible!
Thanks